# Dump connected drives serials and users

Tags: powershell, csv, output, concatenation

I need to list users of a connected drive and it's serial # in an output file. I'll be connecting between 12-24 drives in arrays at a time. I would like to be able to put the assigned drive letters into a variable. And then have the entire script loop for each connected drive. dumping serial + linking it to the users of that drive in a CSV output file

How can I put the assigned drive letters into an array?

```
$(get-physicaldisk; get-childitem -path (array variable):\Users) | add-content C:\path\to\my\output.csv
```

almost gets the output I need when I try this on a single drive. But I'd really like to clean it up and only display the important info (`PSChildName`) excluding all default, public admin accounts to reduce duplicate un-needed info.

I wanted this to work

```
$(get-physicaldisk | select-object FriendlyName, SerialNumber)-$(get-childitem -path L:\Users| select-object PSChildName)
```

but it did not

I need it to grab the serial for each drive - and output the users associated with that drive … i'm struggling with making the output look the way I want.

For each - drive in array - output ((serial #) + (users on the drive)) amending my .csv

After much plugging and chugging i'm now here, thanks to everyone's help

```
function Get-UsersOnDrive([string[]]$DriveLetters){
     if (!$DriveLetters){
         $DriveLetters = Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk | %{$_.Name -replace ":", ""}
     }

     foreach($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters)
        {
         $SerialNumber =  get-partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -ErrorAction Ignore | get-disk | select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
         $path = $DriveLetter + ":\Users"
         $Users = get-childitem -path $path | select-object PSChildName

            $Users | %{
             $OutPut = new-object PsCustomObject
             $OutPut | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $SerialNumber -PassThru |
                 Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Username -Value $_
             return $OutPut
            }
         }
}

 Get-UsersOnDrive -DriveLetters @("C") |  Export-Csv -Path C:\sample\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. You need drive letter and its serial number? Could you show desired output example?

Comment: sorry, No i'm assuming i'll know the drive letters before hand, Imagine an array of 12 drives connected to my tower - assignment starts at F so array would be (F, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T) So for each - pref in .csv SerialNumber- Users

Comment: Could it be as easy as - $DeviceID = (F:\, J:\, K:\, L:\ ..)             then a foreach ($DeviceID in $DeviceID)

Comment: You can specify an array with @() consturct. Like so `$Devices = @('F:', 'J:', 'K:', 'L:')` and then do foreach loop `foreach ($Device in $Devices){Do-This to $Device}`

Comment: you want serial number, Users on drive?

Comment: so, $Devices = @('F:', 'J:', 'K:', 'L:')  foreach ($Device in $Devices){$(get-physicaldisk | select-object FriendlyName, SerialNumber)-$(get-childitem -path $DeviceUsers| select-object PSChildName) | export csv C:\path\to\my\output.csv

Comment: @ArcSet correct, I'm hoping to clean it up so I get a list, I'm ok with the serial# repeating for each user on the drive. I can worry about those duplicates later. But being able to link each user to the correct serial # is vital

Comment: What verison of windows?

Comment: @ArcSet windows 10 1803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what i came up with and its rough

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk | %{
    $DriveLetter = $_.Name -replace ":", ""
    $SerialNumber = get-partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter | get-disk | select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
    $Users = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | select -ExpandProperty LocalPath | ?{$_ -like "$DriveLetter*"} | %{
        $_ -replace '.*\\'
    }
    $Users | %{
        $OutPut = new-object PsCustomObject
        $OutPut | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $SerialNumber -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Username -Value $_
        return $OutPut
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\sample\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

A. Get WMI LogicalDisk (gets you the drive letters)

B. Pass the **$DriveLetter** into a get-partition and get the **SerialNumber** property value.

C. Get Users Profile path, then find the ones on the current drive and replace everything except for the last slash, which is the username

D. Foreach user on drive we create a Custom Object and add the properties SerialNumber and Username, then return output and export to CSV

Here is a function that you can call to get users on drive as well

```
function Get-UsersOnDrive([string[]]$DriveLetters){
    if (!$DriveLetters){
        $DriveLetters = Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk | %{$_.Name -replace ":", ""}
    }

    foreach($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters){

        $SerialNumber =  get-partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -ErrorAction Ignore | get-disk | select -ExpandProperty SerialNumber

        $Users = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | select -ExpandProperty LocalPath | ?{$_ -like "$DriveLetter*"} | %{
            $_ -replace '.*\\'
        }

        $Users | %{
            $OutPut = new-object PsCustomObject
            $OutPut | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $SerialNumber -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Username -Value $_
            return $OutPut
        }
    }
}

Get-UsersOnDrive -DriveLetters @("C","V","F") |  Export-Csv -Path C:\sample\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you remove -DriveLetters parameter and the drives then it will check all drives

Comment: this looks like it should work, however i'm getting a weird error, First it was b/c the .csv didn't exist. now... im getting get-partition : No MSFT_Partition objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'E'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:3 char:21
+     $SerialNumber = get-partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter | get-dis ...
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:Char) [Get-Partition], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_DriveLetter,Get-Partition

Comment: How proficient are you with powershell? I am wondering how much of a explanation and fix i need to do :) But ill go ahead and make error handling for this

Comment: quite limited proficiency. . . However, i'm pulling your example apart piece by piece to try and make it work for my scenario. I appreciate the help, and quick response.

Comment: OK :) i went at this like you had a deeper understanding which is ok :) ill make something a little more easy to understand

Comment: much appreciated, I enjoy a good challenge, so i'm still plugging and chugging over here. but will also accept any easier approach lol

Comment: this is working for the C drive. however, when I change the drive letters to match attached drives in my array, I do not get any output or error. The C: drive output works like a charm

Comment: There are no user profiles on that drive. You requested Users on the drive and that is based on profile attached to computer. What did you mean by Users on that drive?

Comment: There are user profiles on that drive. Understand, I'm taking drives from towers / laptops / etc and hooking them into an array, and then running this script. will need to do this on about 4k drives

Comment: thats not how user profiles work.User profile is tied to the OS or roaming. What you are looking for is folders that indicate a user is there. But i dont know the folder structure. And i cant tell uf the drives are just list of users . You would ned to find something in common with each user in order for me to write something

Comment: Correct! that is indeed what i'm looking for "folders that indicate a user is there" I've got a command that can list my connected drive letters, I'd like to put those into an array, and loop the function you have created for each drive letter in the array

Comment: sort of like copying the output of a 'dir' of (drive letter):\Users I can exclude the duplicates later (like admin / public) etc

Comment: I replaced Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | select -ExpandProperty LocalPath | ?{$_ -like "$DriveLetter*"} | %{
            $_ -replace '.*\\'   >>> to  $(get-childitem -path (X:)\Users| select-object PSChildName)

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets the disk serial number. I am not sure why that is needed. Will this give you a start?

```
function Get-DiskSerialNumber {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0)]
    [string] $DriveLetter
)

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Where-Object DeviceId -eq $DriveLetter |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition |
    Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
}

& openfiles /query /fo csv |
    Select-Object -Skip 5 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header @('ID','USER','TYPE','PATH') |
    Select-Object -Property USER,@{name='DRIVE';expression={$_.PATH.Substring(0,2)}} |
    Sort-Object -Property DRIVE,USER -Unique |
    Select-Object -Property *,
         @{name='SERIALNUMBER';expression={(Get-DiskSerialNumber -Drive $_.DRIVE).SerialNumber}}
```